# Is it allowed to have sex in a home where death has taken place in last 40 days?

Tags: sex, death, limitation

Wether it is prohibited to do sex in house where the death take place or with in 40 days of it?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Why shouldn't it be permissible? Elaborate! And why are you asking about 40 days?

Comment: Because someone said with in 40 days after death rouh of the died person get round of the house. N ethically its not good that someone died in your house n you r having sex.

Comment: @MrsSheraz That is not true. After death, a soul moves to barzakh which is a different dimension from ours.

Answer (score 1):

Where is the narration in Quran and sunnat to prohibit a lawfully wedded couple from intercourse for 40 days in whose family a death has occurred.

A woman had intercourse with her husband the day their son died. She didnt mention the death when her husband returned but after ejaculation, she mentioned this and said I hope Allah replaces our dead one with a better one.

This incident is present in book called gems and jewels published by darussalam saudi Arabia.